# $f(g(x))=g(2)x$, linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I saw an exercise with this unfamiliar for me linear transformation and I would like some help to find its matrix.

$f:\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]$, $f(g(x))=g(2)x$

Here's my thought:

So let $B=\left \{ u_{1},u_{2},u_{3}\right \}=\left \{ (x^2+x+1),(x),(1)\right \}$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]$.

Then:

$f(u_{1})=(2^2+2+1)x=7x$

$f(u_{2})=2x$

$f(u_{3})=1$

So the matrix of $f$ in respect of $B$ is

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
7 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

Is this correct? Or anywhere near correct?

Comment: What is $g(2)$ in the title? Where does $x^2+x+1$ come from?

Comment: It's another function. I'm gonna change it to g(x) just to make it clearer

Comment: I think OP means $\phi(x) = x^2+x+1$, a standard notation for Fibonacci-related discussions...

Comment: Sorry guys I made it a bit more specific, sorry for the confusion

Comment: It is not clearer to me, what $g$ is. Just another function? Then take one with $g(2)=0$. So $f=0$ and we obtain the zero matrix.

Comment: That's all the info the excercise gives.. You think it may be a typo and mean $f(g(x))=g(2x)$ ?

Comment: You say "Here's my thought:", and you come up with $x^2+x+1$. How could you come up with that? Why not $x^2,x,1$ as a basis?

Comment: Dumb question: Is this to do with eigenvectors? I think $f(g(x))=g(2)x$ is like $ABx = \lambda x$ where $\lambda=g(2)$ is an eigenvalue

Answer (score 1):

I see in the comments that there's some confusion as to what the question is. Since we can't look at your sources, we can't say whether you've copied the question correctly or whether there was something different.

That being said, the question you presented is perfectly meaningful. And your solution is almost correct. The only mistake is in your calculation of $f(u_3)$, which instead must be
$$f(u_3)=u_3(2)x=1x=x,$$
so the matrix of $f$ with respect to $B$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
7 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Some commented that your choice of a basis is strange. I agree that it's strange, but it's not wrong: $B=\left\{x^2+x+1,x,1\right\}$ **is a basis** of $\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]$. It's an unusual choice; people typically choose the standard basis $S=\left\{x^2,x,1\right\}$ for this vector space. But if it was given to you or even if you chose yourself to use it, there's nothing actually wrong with it.

**NOTE:** Of course, if the question is different — for example, if it's supposed to be $f(g(x))=g(2x)$ instead — then the answer will be different too.

Comment: Thank you very much! I chose that basis cause it's the one our proffesor usually tells us to use. But I see here how $x^{2}$ instead of $x^2+x+1$ is more usuful.

Thanks again